# Cannot load .class file with ResourcePatternResolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classloader

I'm trying to load a .class file into Spring project. I tried this:

```
            WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();

            ResourcePatternResolver resolver = (ResourcePatternResolver)context;
            Resource[] res = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/opt/validation/*.class");

            resolver.getClassLoader().loadClass("ValidateProcessor");
```

But I I get error `Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ValidateProcessor`

The file ValidateProcessor.class is present into that directory but it's not found. Can you give me some advice how to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the full qualified class name. In case the class is located in a package `opt.validation` you should load:

```
resolver.getClassLoader().loadClass("opt.validation.ValidateProcessor");
```